# Which mathematics areas are important to be strong in for research in mathematical modelling of neuroscience/human psychology?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, mathematical-modeling, applications, biology

I’m guessing ODEs/PDEs would play a big role - I wonder exactly what methods from ODE/PDEs are used in this kind of research? I also wonder whether stochastic processes and stochastic differential equations are also important?

Also, would anyone say that a firm grounding in either Fluid Mechanics or Quantum Mechanics would have any relevance? I additionally read somewhere that neuroscience could have links with information theory?

I suppose that frequentist/bayesian statistics wouldn’t be too relevant though?

Comment: Statistics, linear algebra, multi-variate calculus, graph theory.

Comment: I knew a professor who studied people who had seizures. He studied brain waves using time series analysis, control theory, and fractional calculus.